# Execution times in Oracle trace file

Tags: oracle

I have a trace file but I cannot understand where the execution time of each of the queries that were made is shown, I suspect it is tim, but I have not been able to find what it means and to what extent of time it is specified in case if it's time, could you please help me

Comment: Please post a snippet of the file you're talking about so that we have some idea what you're seeing.

Comment: How has this file been created (`DBMS_MONITOR`, `ALTER SESSION` ...) ? What is the trace file suffix (`.trc` or something else) ? Did you use `TKPROF` on the raw trace file ?

Comment: I was seeing it as it had been generated so it was that I did not understand it, use the tkprof tool to translate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use TKPROF using something like:

```
tkprof mytracefile.trc myoutputfile.txt sort=exeela
```

It will show the slowest SQL statement first in file `myoutputfile.txt`.

For each SQL statement you will have similar ouput:

```
SELECT * 
FROM emp, dept 
WHERE emp.deptno = dept.deptno;

call   count      cpu    elapsed     disk    query current    rows
---- -------  -------  --------- -------- -------- -------  ------
Parse     11     0.08      0.18        0       0       0         0
Execute   11     0.23      0.66        0       3       6         0
Fetch     35     6.70      6.83      100   12326       2       824
------------------------------------------------------------------
total     57     7.01      7.67      100   12329       8       826

Misses in library cache during parse: 0
```

Elapsed columns is the database time spent to run the query: `Parse` = query compilation, `Execute`= execution time for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE and `Fetch`= execution time for SELECT.